# Is there a relationship between the integrand in Green's Theorem and the test for finding an integrating factor for a differential form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, soft-question

Green's Theorem has the formula
$$
\int_C Mdx+Ndy=\int\int_D\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right)dxdy
$$

There is also a well known test for finding an integrating factor for a form $Mdx+Ndy$ depending on whether $\frac{1}{M}\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right)$ or 
$\frac{1}{N}\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right)$ depend only on $x$ or $y$.

Is there a deeper relationship between the $\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right)$ showing up in both things, or is it coincidence?